# How do we compare a list of strings to just a string

Tags: java

I have:

```
String[] Value={"Available to trade at 12 30","I love sherlock"}
```

and I want to check if **sherlock** is present in the list without using `for each` loop.

Comment: You have an *array*. Iterate through the container and use `contains()`

Comment: "sherlock" isn't present in the array, though. It is present *within an element* of the array...

Comment: As per @cricket_007 comment you want to find  a string in array or array of element?

Answer (score 1):

Java streams are handy for this

```
String[] value = {"Available to trade at 12 30", "I love sherlock"};
Stream.of(value).anyMatch(s -> s.contains("sherlock"));
```

If you want to get the string that has sherlock:

```
String[] value = {"Available to trade at 12 30", "I love sherlock"};
Stream.of(value).filter(s -> s.contains("sherlock")).findFirst().get();
```

Or use findAny(), if you don't care about order. Both findAny and findFirst return an Optional, which will be empty if there are no matches and .get() will throw.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

Arrays.asList(Value).contains("string to be searched");

Better option is to convert array to list so that multiple functions can be used

Comment: This doesn't provide the solution for how to get "sherlock", though

Comment: Please provide the code in your answer instead of as a link

Comment: String str = "I love sherlock";String[] splited = str.split("\\b+");Arrays.asList(splited).contains("sherlock")

Comment: That's a comment. Please find the appropriate "edit" link under your answer. Don't use the comments for code

Answer (score 0):

The problem inherently requires you to iterate through all the elements in the array, essentially performing a for each. However, you can choose whether you want good memory performance or good execution time for the lookup.

If you want good memory performance leave it as is and iterate through the list every time you perform the check. For good execution time you should create a hashset and populate it with every substring present in the list. This is a bit time consuming and memory-intensive but once you have built your set you can keep it and reuse, making each runtime check only take log n time.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the array into a single String and then use the String .contains method.

```
String entireArray = Arrays.toString(Value);
boolean sherlockPresent = entireArray.contains("sherlock");
```